# On INSERT, can the Primary Key's value go into another, non-null field on the same table?

Tags: sql-server

I'm guessing the answer is 'no' because this seems absurd, but I have a rare situation where this needs to happen:

Given a table with three fields:

```
ID, PK, smallint, not null
Code, Varchar(5), not null
Name, VarChar(50), not null
```

Can I magically insert the ID field into CODE with an INSERT statement?

```
INSERT INTO MyTable (Code, Name)
    VALUES (CAST([ID's new Value] AS VARCHAR(5)),'New Name')
```

**NOTE:**  Changes to the table's structure (or the database) would be overkill.  I want to accomplish by appending it at the end of a stored procedure.

Comment: @HLGEM yes, ID is an Identity.  I don't know its value until after is saved.

Comment: also, "needs" is a bit strong. Let's say it's the "preferred" scenario for this use case.

Comment: Your `ID` field is `not null`, which means it can't be `NULL`.

Comment: Can the value of `Code` ever be updated to be different from `ID`? If not maybe you could just replace the existing column with a computed column.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have an identity and this is not something you do every time (when a trigger makes the most sense), this is not very straightforward to do. Basically what you do is insert a fake value into the Code field (because it is required) and then output the id value of the inserted table, then update the table with the ID. Of course (as with any multistatement action, you should use  try-catch  and explicit transactions, rolling back all actions if any one fails).

```
DECLARE @output TABLE (Id INT))
INSERT INTO MyTable (Code, Name) 
OUTPUT Inserted.ID INTO @output
    VALUES ('test','New Name') 

UPDATE m
SET code = o.Id
FROM    Mytable m
JOIN @output o ON m.Id = o.id
```

Answer (score 1):

The way that you accomplish this is with a database trigger: the trigger fires as a result of the insert statement, so it has the value inserted into the table. It can then do an update.

At least, that's what you can do in Oracle. I don't know how much control a SQL-Server trigger gives you, or when an identity field is given a value, but here's the doc: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189799.aspx

Answer (score 0):

You might consider using an AFTER INSERT trigger to copy the value for you.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa258254(v=sql.80).aspx